# Не работает Google карта в release версии приложения

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-play, google-maps

Такая проблема, требуется подключить к мобильному приложению Google карту, в debug версии всё работает нормально, но как только компилирую release версию и выставляю в Google Play, после скачивания карта перестаёт работать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В console.cloud.google всё заполнил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле Manifest всё прописал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.project.avtomoy">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
        <activity android:name=".UserAgreementActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
        </meta-data>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            />
        <activity android:name=".ui.home.ComplexAdapter" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AutoRegActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_auto_reg"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Контрольную сумму получил при помощи команды:`keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\Programm\Java\android-stepcar_part2\my-release-key.keystore" -alias alias_name`

В чём может быть проблема, мб я что то забыл?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прикладывать в виде текста а не картинок :)

Comment: @Andrew, ок, учту, поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить ключ api в release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml файл